# Force IE to display image if the extension does not match the filetype?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, dom

I have a front-end uploader on my site that has been in commission for two years or so. Due to a programming error on my part, images were coming out like this:

```
image1.png.jpg
```

I never noticed this error due to them displaying correctly in Chrome/Firefox. Today I noticed they don't work in IE and I receive the following console error:

```
DOM7009: Unable to decode image at URL: 'https://ygoprodeck.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Blue-eyeSUTOKaiba-deck-32682.png'.
Blue-eyeSUTOKaiba-deck-32682.png
```

Unfortunately I probably have 2000+ of these images so I'm not sure how to elegantly go about fixing this.

I'm looking for both short term and long term solutions. I'd envisage that the long term solution is fixing the file names (maybe I can use a program to mass update them).

**My Config**:

Shared Hosting

Apache

PHP7.2

**Header Results** from https://www.webconfs.com/http-header-check.php
Using Image: https://ygoprodeck.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/MAGICIALMERCHANTOTK2019-deck-32685.png

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK =>
Date => Thu, 03 Jan 2019 12:51:01 GMT
Content-Type => image/png
Content-Length => 350116
Connection => close
Set-Cookie => __cfduid=dfa00236e5232f27b973e72d93e528d5b1546519860; expires=Fri, 03-Jan-20 12:51:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.ygoprodeck.com; HttpOnly
X-Frame-Options => SAMEORIGIN
Last-Modified => Thu, 03 Jan 2019 12:31:27 GMT
Cache-Control => public, max-age=2419200
Expires => Thu, 31 Jan 2019 12:51:00 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options => nosniff
X-XSS-Protection => 1; mode=block
CF-Cache-Status => MISS
Accept-Ranges => bytes
Expect-CT => max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
Server => cloudflare
CF-RAY => 493598263c4dc506-ORD
```

File is then run through an image checker https://www.get-metadata.com/result/608c84b5-0062-4469-ac52-b3240334c85c

```
File Type JPEG
File Type Extension jpg
Mime Type image/jpeg
```

Comment: Why do it on front-end? Batch rename them from your server.

Comment: Your long term solution is probably just as quick, if not quicker than a short term hack. Most OS's it's normally not a big job to batch rename files.

Comment: Further update, upon downloading the image it's shown as only .png. I ran it through an online photo checker and it indeed shows it being a jpg. I'm a bit stumped now since I can't simply change the extension, I would probably need to convert all the files. https://www.get-metadata.com/result/93aede68-b0c1-4d09-8b3e-aafc51d1c8a5

Comment: Why can't you change the extension? Surely that's an IE bug (or server misconfig) that they do see it as png files, but why renaming your files is not an option? Note that after further thinking, your server should be responsible of sending the correct content-type header. Can you double check what is sent?

Comment: Hey there, I updated the OP with more info. The header is being seen as png but the actual mime type of the image is jpeg. If I rename the file in windows to image1.png then it still shows as being mime type jpeg which leads me to believe I'd need to convert them. On top of that, I checked how much images I would need to convert and it's 40k+. Way off my original estimation. At this stage I'm looking for some way to stop IE bugging out with it. Maybe removing nosniff header somehow?

Comment: Oh and the easy solution would be to just remove .png and leave it as .jpg but all the links on the site would break then as they are inserted and linked in as .png files.